# How to query Sql Db to get the students' result for only those who complete all exam's stages

Tags: sql-server-2008

`ExamsStagesTbl`

```
 CourseId  StageId
 1         1
 1         2 
 2         1 
 3         1 
 3         2 
 3         3 
 3         4
```

`StudentsResultTbl`

```
StudentId   CourseId   StageId   StageDgree 
23          1          1          30 
23          1          2          25 
23          3          1          30 
10          1          1          27 
10          2          1          30
```

Please how to get all records from the table  `StudentsResultTbl` for only those finish all the exam's stages.
the Scenario: 
from the above tables:
Student 23 has exam in courses 1 and 3 but he only finish course 1.
Student 10 has exam in course 1 and 2 but he only finish course 2.
so how to get the result(if the student has exam in all course's stages) using SQL statement

Comment: Do you want those students who completed at least one couse with all stages or completed all courses with all stages?

Comment: I need to display  all courses' result  if he student complete all exams' stages  in the course.  e.g: student 23 complete all stages in course 1 but not in course 3, and student 10  only course 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @courses TABLE
    (
      CourseID INT ,
      StageID INT
    )
DECLARE @results TABLE
    (
      StudentID INT ,
      CourseID INT ,
      StageID INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @courses
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 1, 2 ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 3, 1 ),
        ( 3, 2 ),
        ( 3, 3 ),
        ( 3, 4 )

INSERT  INTO @results
VALUES  ( 23, 1, 1 ),
        ( 23, 1, 2 ),
        ( 23, 3, 1 ),
        ( 10, 1, 1 ),
        ( 10, 2, 1 );

WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   CourseID ,
                        COUNT(*) AS StageCount
               FROM     @courses c
               GROUP BY CourseID
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   StudentID ,
                        CourseID ,
                        COUNT(DISTINCT StageID) AS StageCount
               FROM     @results c
               GROUP BY StudentID ,
                        CourseID
             )
    SELECT  cte2.StudentID ,
            cte2.CourseID
    FROM    cte2
            JOIN cte1 ON cte1.CourseID = cte2.CourseID
    WHERE   cte1.StageCount = cte2.StageCount
    ORDER BY cte2.StudentID ,
             cte2.CourseID
```

Output:

```
StudentID   CourseID
10          2
23          1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.studentid,c.courseid  from (select courseid,count(*) as no from studentcompleteallstages group by courseid) c inner join ( select studentid,courseid ,count(*) as no
 from (select b.studentid,b.courseid,b.stageid from studentcompleteallstages a inner join tblstudents b on a.courseid=b.courseid and a.stageid=b.stageid
 ) as sub group by studentid,courseid  ) d on c.courseid = d.courseid and c.no=d.no
```